# Enable cross domain integrated windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, security, iis

I have a web application (say app1) which is hosted in a IIS server virtual directory. 
This web application needs Integrated Windows Authentication for its functioning.

I need to integrate this web application with another product which does not use supply me windows credentials.

This application sends me an http request in a specific format.
I need to validate the request and redirect it to app1 with valid windows credentials so that it logs in smoothly.

I have created another application for this purpose
This is hosted on a separate virtual directory.
It has IIS anonymous and asp.net anonymous authentication enabled.

the pseudo code is as follows :

app2

parse request
if request sucessful 
     get windows credentials
     get identity using credentials
     reponse.redirect(app1.aspx)

But app1 authentication fails, IE asks me for credentials again.
Ideally IE should not ask me for credentials.

What would be the security context sent in the request to app1.

How can I trace the authentication failure at iis and asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need a trust relationship between the domains.

The response.redirect just sends a response back to the browser which then makes a request for the page in the redirect. So the identity is the identity of the browser.